# multiple checkbox value in array in php

Tags: php

I have one form which contain product information and one field which have two(2) check box for status(want to post advertise for that particular product or not.)and i have one field which is for "add more" it will clone whole `div` and also check boxes so i have more then one output but I don't have getting single value.

```
<div>
     <label>I want to Advertise This Item</label>
     <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chkyes[]" id="chkyes[]"/>
     Yes
     <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="chkyes[]" id="chkyes[]"/>
     No 
</div>
```

Above code is for selecting checkbox, and below code which echo value in array but I don't get the value of checkbox.

```
if(count($_POST)){
    $len = count($_POST['producttitle']);
    for ($i=1; $i < $len; $i++){
        echo $_POST['chkyes'][$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't give id's like chkyes[] give it as chkyes1, chkyes2

Comment: Where exactly is the form element with name of `producttitle`?

Comment: Oops, right. I think HTML5 allows these characters in IDs, but the real problem is that he has duplicate IDs. IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 2):

why you dont use foreach?

for eg

```
if (isset($_POST['chkyes'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['chkyes'] as $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first approach:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='chkyes[1]'>
<input type='checkbox' name='chkyes[2]'>
<input type='checkbox' name='chkyes[3]'>
```

This way you could access them in PHP with

```
foreach ($_POST['chkyes'] as $id=>$checked){
   if ($checked =='on')
    //process your id
 }
```

The second approach:Set value's attributes on checkboxes:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='chkyes[]' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='chkyes[]' value='2'>
<input type='checkbox' name='chkyes[]' value='3'>
```

With this you'll receive only checked values:

```
foreach ($_POST['chkyes'] as $id){
    //process your id
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Array of input start from an index of 0, and use `$_POST['chkyes']` instead of `$_POST['producttitle']`

```
 if(count($_POST)){
     $len = count($_POST['chkyes']);
     for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++){
         echo $_POST['chkyes'][$i];
     }
 }
```

also you can't give id's like chkyes[] give it as chkyes1, chkyes2

Comment: using characters like `[,]` are valid. problem might be duplication of ids

Comment: yup i said for id only that it can be an array

Comment: You mentioned about `chkyes[]` being invalid.

Comment: for id, 'you can't give id's like chkyes[]'

Comment: if i give id like chkyes1[] and chkyes2[] then also it gives error Undefined offset: 2 and returns 0 as value.

Comment: @Anamika:You can... see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @user3164797 it should be id like chkyes1 and chkyes2 and use $_POST['chkyes'] for getting len variable

Comment: still getting Undefined offset:

Comment: <div>
                <label>I want to Advertise This Item</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chkyes[]" id="chkyes1"/> Yes
                <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="chkyes[]" id="chkyes2"/>
                No </div>
code page:- 
<?php
 if(count($_POST))
  {
   $len = count($_POST['producttitle']);
 for ($i=1; $i < $len; $i++)
{
$sql_product = mysql_query("insert product set productname='".$_POST['producttitle'][$i]."',Adv_status='".$_POST['chkyes'][$i]."'");
      
   }
  }
?>

Answer (score 1):

**Try Below code**

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit'] == 'submit'){
    $len = count($_POST['chkyes']);
    for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++){
        echo $_POST['chkyes'][$i];
    }
}
?>


<form name="test" method="POST">
<div>
     <label>I want to Advertise This Item</label>
     <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chkyes[]" id="chkyes[]"/>
     Yes
     <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="chkyes[]" id="chkyes[]"/>
     No 
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only checkboxes that are checked are submitted in the form. They'll be collected in an array `$_POST['chkyes']`, but the indexes won't be the same as corresponding text inputs. You need to process them with their own `foreach` loop, not the same loop as for other inputs.

For what you're doing, why aren't you using radio buttons or a single checkbox? What if the user checks both Yes and No?